# PHP how to transform btc to usd

Tags: php

I want to make a function in PHP witch transforms bitcoin into usd, here's my code:

```
<?php
    function usd2btc($btc) {
      $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,    
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,   
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",      
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,    
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,    
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,     
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 2,      
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false   
      );

      $ch      = curl_init( "https://api.coingate.com/v2/rates/merchant/BTC/USD" ); //BTC2USD exange
      curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
      $content = curl_exec( $ch ); // Gets the page's content
      $err     = curl_errno( $ch ); // Gets the CURL error number if there is error
      $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); // Gets the CURL error text if there is error
      curl_close( $ch );




 if ($btc !== 0) {             
   return round($btc/$content, 2);         
 } else {            
   return 0.00;           
 }      
}

?>
```

When I run the function for example:

```
<p>0.002฿ = <?php htmlspecialchars(usd2btc(0.002)); ?>$</p>
```

It doesn't return anything, not even 0. Do you guys have some solutions? help.

Comment: Seems the request did not succeed. Did you try echoing `$errmsg`?

Comment: I tried to remove `curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );` from the code and now the function just returns bitcoin value, ignoring the division, `$errmsg` outputs nothing.